# Fingerprint scanner data disk space

Tags: fingerprint, diskspace, biometrics

How much disk space required for storing one finger's fingerprint data? I'm trying to predict disk space requirement for designing a fingerprint scanner with internal hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what standard you're using, but assuming [ISO/IEC 19794-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50864) minutia based templates they're on the order of 500 bytes / template. There's naturally some variance but that's a fair starting point for templates *containing only minutia* for other back of the napkin calculations.